# do we need parameters.json file ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am planning to deploy some services through ARM template in Azure. my question is every service file has a parameter.json file the repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates. but what if I can directly replace the parameter using the replace token task and then I can continue with the deployment. is there any special advantage using the parameter apart from manipulating the input and assigning it to the variable and using?

for e.g

```
 "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCount')]"
      },
```

instead of this

```
"sku": {
        "name": "#{sku}#",
        "capacity": "#{capacity}#"
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking what you are saying is legit but I have seen couple of scenarios that you would be easier to keep the param file:

1. You splited your ARM template to many files like when deploying an Azure Function that requires many other resources, then it will be easier to share the same param file.
2. Your env doesn't require a lot of complications so you had a param file per environment then you can using **n of tasks** to deploy same ARM to different Resource Groups or whatever other than having to maintain **n Tasks to Replace Tokens** plus the **n Tasks to deploy** and then having **X variables** in the pipeline to replace these variables and manage **their scope**.